# Automate installation using bash script - how to answer dialogs written with ncurses

Tags: bash, ubuntu, automation, ncurses, apt-get

How to automatically answer dialogs (written with ncurses) during installation in Ubuntu? For example during postfix installation.

Comment: On SO you give and take information, and so far you've only been taking. How about giving something back to the people who helped you?

Comment: Yep, please accept all the answers that helped you. Simply click the check-mark.

Answer (score 0):

Those dialogs are a part of `debconf` which is a configuration tool for Debian packages. It has many front-ends, `ncurses` is one of them.

You can use `dpkg-reconfigure -f noninteractive`, use `debconf`'s Bash library, reconfigure `debconf` itself to be always non-interactive, etc.

And there's also a package called `debconf-utils`:

> This package contains some small utilities to aid users and developers. There are utilities to help manage debconf databases, others to manage translated template files and a program to communicate directly with debconf from the command line.